# XUnit Deployment Directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest, xunit

I would like to deploy some data items at deployment directory before running the tests in XUnit. It should be something equivalent to DeploymentItem("testdataFile.csv").

But I can't really realize the location of that directory. Is there any deployment Directory exist while running unit tests at XUnit. While we know DeploymentItem is mstest attribute. Is there any thing relevent to Xunit?

Comment: the root of the unit test project...

Comment: what exactly is the root of unit test project?
Let say i created sample x Unit test project, what would be it's root? /bin/Debug?
In this case, I don't want to rely on Debug directory.

Comment: Assuming you checked the create project in its own directory checkbox: solution1/someproject.tests/[myrootishere]